# Is it natural/common to say "deduct conclusion"?

Tags: word-usage

This morning I sent a report regarding a software issue.

> Based on the logging and screenshot, I **deduct this conclusion**:
>
> 1. some undefined error happened on the server side, which needs server dev to track
> 2. the error code crashes the client application which needs client dev to add more error handling
>    ...

Is it natural/common to say "deduct conclusion" in this context?

[Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deduct%20this%20conclusion%2C%20deduct%20conclusion%2C%20deduct%20a%20conclusion&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=) seems to indicate that nobody says it that way.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try "deduce" instead of "deduct". The latter form usually means to subtract something.   You would not usually say "deduce a conclusion", but rather "deduce this", or "come to this conclusion", or "arrive at this conclusion".

Comment: Thank you. Is it clear and natural to say "Based on the logging and screenshot, it comes to this conclusion ..."

Comment: No, "I come to this conclusion" would fit, meaning that a person has decided something based on evidence. "It comes to this conclusion" would mean that something (not a person) had stopped.

Answer (score 1):

I've personally never heard or seen "deduct conclusion" in written or oral communication. Some popular alternatives are "In conclusion", "To conclude", To summerize" or "The takeaway is".

Comment: The alternatives in the answer are really handy. Thank you. How do I make it a complete sentence in a formal setting? "Based on the logging and screenshot, to conclude" doesn't seems fluent.

Comment: Based on the logging, I conclude....

Answer (score 0):

Usually one reaches a conclusion or comes to it so I would suggest

> Based on the logging and screenshot, I reached this conclusion:
> Based on the logging and screenshot, I came to this conclusion: