# "come to this conclusion" vs. "came to this conclusion"

Tags: tense

I sent an email yesterday to report my analysis regarding a software issue.

> Based on the logging and screenshot, I **come** to this conclusion:
>
> 1. some undefined error happened on the server side, which needs server dev to track
> 2. the error code crashes the client application which needs client dev to add more error handling
>    ...

Should I have used past tense there?

> ... I **came** to this conclusion ...

I guess present tense is more natural in this context. I'd just like a double check, as [a post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/253598/117396) suggests past tense.

Answer (score 1):

“Came” would actually be more common, as you’ve already came to the conclusion at the time you write the email, so the concluding happened in the past.

“Come” is actually valid, and is a way of speaking as though you are coming to the conclusion as you are writing. It carries more of a storytelling effect and is perhaps a bit too formal or fancy for ordinary writing.

Comment: I would also offer the suggestion "I have come to this conclusion:" which I actually prefer.